# How to get the selected Item value from combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selecteditem

With the following code the combobox cbAdditionalFields is not holding the selected value in SelectedItem property. How to get the selected item property of the combobox? and on selection changed not focus

```
var userFields = recordType.UserFields.Where(u => u.Format == UserFieldFormats.String);

cbAdditionalFields.DataSource = userFields.ToList();
cbAdditionalFields.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: Set `DisplayMember` before `DataSource`

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for you

```
private void cbAdditionalFields_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... Get the ComboBox.
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    //string value = comboBox.SelectedItem as string;
    UserField value = comboBox.SelectedItem as UserField;
    Console.WriteLine(value.Name);
}
```

Now `value` contains the currently selected item in the ComboBox.

Comment: SelectedItem is not having the "Name" property, it is showing as an object of type UserField

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this issue by setting the selected index or selected value property of the ComboBox.
cb.selectedIndex = 0;

Comment: I get an error "Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty ValueMember."